# python execute order issue

Tags: python, tkinter, delay

[image]

```
from tkinter import *
import time

def check_Log_In():
    global name
    name = ent_id.get()
    global pw
    pw = ent_pw.get()
    alert = Label(Log_In)
    alert.config(text="Welcome, {}.".format(name))
    alert.grid(row=3,columnspan=3,padx=20,pady=20)
    time.sleep(3) 

Log_In=Tk()

ent_id = Entry(Log_In)
ent_id.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=20,pady=20)

ent_pw = Entry(Log_In, show="*")
ent_pw.grid(row=2,column=1,padx=20,pady=20)

btn_Log_In = Button(Log_In, text="Start", command=check_Log_In)
btn_Log_In.grid(row=1,column=2,rowspan=2,padx=20,pady=20)

Log_In.mainloop()
```

---

I want to make 3 seconds of delay after showing "Welcome ~"
but by this code,

it delays 3 seconds first, and then shows "Welcome ~"

How do I fix it?

Comment: Use ```.after()```. And what will you do after delaying?

Comment: I want to Execute  another *.py after showing some kinda welcome text,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.after()` method. This will delay the function by 3 seconds (3000 milliseconds).

```py
def start_new_file():
    print('New file started')

def check_Log_In():
    global name, pw
    name = ent_id.get()
    pw = ent_pw.get()
    alert = Label(Log_In, text=f"Welcome, {name}.")
    alert.grid(row=3, columnspan=3, padx=20, pady=20)

    Log_In.after(3000, start_new_file)
```